# Problems with Avalanche-imagine in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle, php-imagine

I'm trying to create thumbnails with Avalanche-imagine bundle. I'm using OS X 10.7 Lion and  MAMP PRO as Apache server.

When I call the filter in the twig file, I get a 500 error.

Here I put the path manually to check it:

```
<img src='{{'store/images/Pictures/P1000665.JPG' | apply_filter('my_thumb')}}'>
```

And I get this message:
    GET

```
http://taller:8888/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/my_thumb/store/images/Pictures/P1000665.JPG 500
```

(Internal Server Error)

[image]

line 35, it's strange because my thumbnails are used far behind

[image]

I installed the bundle following this instructions: https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle

I have to say that I had several problems installing it because composer.phar gave me an error message:

"Problem 1
    - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
    - Installation request for symfony/icu 1.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.0]."

I solved it adding this line in the composer.json requirements:

```
    "symfony/icu": "1.0.*",
```

Once installed, I could install the AvalancheImageBundle with the composer.

Then I changed AppKernel as they said in the instruction with this line:

```
new Avalanche\Bundle\ImagineBundle\AvalancheImagineBundle(),
```

but I didn't change the autoload file, as I had to do when I installed FOSUserBundle. Do I have to add anything there?

I tried with this, but it didn't solved my problem:

```
$loader->add('imagine', __DIR__.'/../vendor/imagine/imagine/lib');
$loader->add('Avalanche123', __DIR__.'/../vendor'):
```

Additional info:

My proyect is in: Symfony2/proyecto/taller/here_are_web_app_vendor_and_src
My apache server aim to: Symfony2/proyecto/taller using the sortcut taller instead of localhost my url is like this:

```
http://taller:8888/web/app_dev.php/
```

My pictures are in the url: Symfony2/proyecto/taller/web/store/images/Pictures/test.jpg
witch url should I give to the filter? I think it is store/images/Pictures/test.jpg

The problem could be in the dependences of the bundle, because I put that line the composer.json?

Maybe should I write something in the autoload file? Any reference to vendor/imagine miss?

Also I tried to install liipImagine bundle, but I couldn't because it said that I had installed imagine 0.3.0 and I needed imagine 0.4.0. How can I uninstall imagine and install the new version to run liipimaginebudle?

appKernel: 
[image]

As you can see, no references to imagine (I guess its integer in Avalanchebundle)

autoload: [image]
 
(no references to avalanche?)

Here is where my pictures are located and you can see how Avalanche created the media folder: [image]

This is my vendor file: [image]

I don't know where is the problem, this is why I put so many information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using LiipImagineBundle.

To install it first I deleted Avalanche reference in composer.json and everything else I wrote in appKernel.php, etc.

Then I did composer.phar update and it deleted also imagine/imagine 0.3.0 vendor library. Finally I installed LiipImagine via composer normally that installed a newer version of imagine/imagine, 0.4.0.

Comment: If you already used Avalanche you also have to rename your calls (you get an error message). Change 'apply_filter' to 'imagine_filter'. You also have to map the configuration (config.yml) from avalanche to LiipImagine because the formatting changed. For that, look up the docu. All in all very straight forward.